# order() Function: Error "Error in order(products$var) : argument 1 is not a vector"

Tags: r

I've searched a lot in the Internet but I didn't find any solutions to my problem. My code is very simple. I want the function to use a supplied "character" to sort a `data.frame` by that column name (`"character"`). My current function is:

```
products=as.data.frame(read.csv("cameras.csv", sep=",", header=T))

ascending=function(var){  
  products_ascending = products[order(products[[var]]),] 
  rownames(products_ascending) <- NULL
  return(products_ascending)
}

ascending(Resolution)

head(products)

  Resolution Zoom   Size Price Screen   Video Settings Sensitivity

1            12     24.0  98.45   750 461000 2073600       20        3200

2         12 26.0 129.11   699 460000 2073600       19        3200

3         16 12.0  55.10   449 460800 2073600       12        3200

4         10 10.7  56.25   290 307500  921600       17        3200

5         12  4.0  53.48   499 460000 2073600        6        3200

6         14 18.0  86.64   138 230000  921600       12        6400
```

I fixed it with: `products_ascending = products[order(products[[var]]),]`

and yes it works but not in a function it returns the Error:

> Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else   .subset2(x,  :
>     object 'Resolution' not found

```
dput(head(products))

structure(list(Resolution = c(12, 12, 16, 10, 12, 14), Zoom = c(24, 
26, 12, 10.7, 4, 18), Size = c(98.45, 129.11, 55.1, 56.25, 53.48, 
86.64), Price = c(750L, 699L, 449L, 290L, 499L, 138L), Screen = c(461000L, 
460000L, 460800L, 307500L, 460000L, 230000L), Video = c(2073600L, 
2073600L, 2073600L, 921600L, 2073600L, 921600L), Settings = c(20L, 
19L, 12L, 17L, 6L, 12L), Sensitivity = c(3200L, 3200L, 3200L, 
3200L, 3200L, 6400L)), .Names = c("Resolution", "Zoom", "Size", 
"Price", "Screen", "Video", "Settings", "Sensitivity"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yes... a little help would be nice, but since you have not provided any help it's going to be difficult. Please post the output of `dput()` applied to  `Resolution`.

Comment: could you provide an example of your data set? use `dput(Resolution)`, and `dput(products)`

Comment: In all probability this is a case of not realizing that the `$`-function is not going to evaluate its argument and that LuddiLuddy thinks that `Resolution`'s value will be substituted into `var`.

Comment: It seems to be getting worse. The questioner is naming his column with the word "character". The possibility of confusion is being multiplied!

Comment: okay i shared know almost the whole code

Answer (score 4):

See this [article](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) that explains how the subsetting functions (`[`, `[[`, `$`) work.

You need to use `products[[var]]`

To quote the relevant part of the article by Hadley Wickham,

"$ is a shorthand operator, where x$y is equivalent to x[["y", exact = FALSE]]".

Answer (score 2):

My guess (we would need to see your data), is you need to use a different subsetting method:

```
ascending=function(var){  
  products_ascending = products[order(products[[var]]),]            
  return(products_ascending)
}
```

You can't subset using a $ and a variable added after it.

Then:

`ascending("Resolution")`

Comment: Okay but the Problem is if im doing this i get the following Error: Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'Resolution' not found         =(

Comment: you will need to share a little of your data to fix this - try `dput(head(Resolution))` and `dput(head(products))` and paste into the main question at the bottom

Comment: great, your problem was you need quotes around "Resolution" - it isn't defined globally, only inside products, so R needs to know you are using it as a character (hence quotes), rather than a variable.